# Remove brackets from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array whose string representation which prints like this

```
['w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04']
```

This a numpy array, is there any way i can remove those brackets, I tried `'.'join(thearray)` but I get:

```
Type Error: sequence item 0: expected instance, Numpy.ndarray found
```

What i would ideally like this to be string representation to print like:

```
'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What constitutes the brackets? Are you expecting `'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'`

Comment: I don't think you can. All numpy arrays look like that.

Comment: Could you post your efforts in code? It's a bit unclear what you mean. Do you want to create a string of the array? Or do you want to print it? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I think you’re confusing the actual array value with its repr or str representation. An array’s repr and str always have brackets in them, but the array itself doesn’t (unless your array has string elements, and those strings are the str representation of other arrays, or something weird like that… in which case, don’t do that)z

Comment: What i was expecting was `'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'`  , like a string ,

Comment: Meanwhile, `'.'join(thearray)` doesn’t work because you’re missing the `.` between the string and the method. I’m pretty sure (not in front of a computer, so I can’t test) that would be a `SyntaxError`, not a `TypeError`. I’m also pretty sure your error string is not actually one Python can generate. Please read [mcve] in the help, and copy and paste the actual error and the actual code that generates it if you want us to debug it.

Comment: I am guessing it is 2d array which gave above error message. Can you try `' '.join(*thearray)`?

Comment: What you were expecting isn’t “like a string”, it’s like four strings’ representations with spaces between them. Python will never insert `' '` into the middle of any object’s representation (unless you explicitly write a really weird `__repr__` method to force it to do so). And, again, the quotes aren’t actually part of each string, they’re part of its representation.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous Yes, my comment was to Ryan, not to you. What he says he wants is not clear, and there’s no way to interpret it that matches what’s in his question. You’re doing a valiant effort to try to drag the information out of him via guessing and hoping he’ll confirm when you guess right, which I applaud, but I doubt it’ll work anyway…

Comment: Sorry for obscurity in the question, What i expected was is there any operation that would take me from [ 'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'] to 'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04', anyways i didnt solve this ,but i have taken a different route to my main problem,So thanks for the suggestions and sorry for the misclarity.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous You may go ahead and downvote,but thanks for your help!

Comment: To be honest ,I dont know ,i was hoping them to be strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your Numpy array, it contains `str` objects, not numeric objects, so `ndarray` cannot work. Also, the array literal (that bracketed text) *has* to be bracketed, or else it will count as multiple arguments.

- `np.array(['w_49c9417','w_b6ae946','w_1596a47','w_b68d04'])` is valid as the argument is a single array literal
- `np.array('w_49c9417','w_b6ae946','w_1596a47','w_b68d04')` isn't because it has four arguments. You cannot remove the brackets from the array literal.

This can be documented in the [SciPy tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html).

However, you can get the `str` representation of that array, and remove the outermost brackets. Simply use `str(arr).lstrip('[').rstrip(']')`

```
arr = np.array(['w_49c9417','w_b6ae946','w_1596a47','w_b68d04'])
print(arr)
print(str(arr))
print(str(arr).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'))
```

The output would be (except the comments after #)

```
['w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'] # arr
['w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'] # str(arr)
'w_49c9417' 'w_b6ae946' 'w_1596a47' 'w_b68d04'   # using lstrip.rightstrip, expected result
```

Comment: @Ryan I have provided an answer for you, but please note it assumes that this "array literal" is really a string. Afterwards, can you clarify that you want to remove the brackets from the *string representation* of that array?